# www folder empty in ionic project

Tags: android, web, ionic-framework, npm, atom-editor

I am trying to create a basic ionic project. I have used the command 
`ionic start myProj blank` to create myself a blank project. I am referring to a tutorial where is shows that the www folder should have css, js and other folders in them. I don't see ay in my project structure.

I have tried reinstalling ionic. Did not help. Currently I have installed

Ionic - 2.2.3 
Node - v6.10.2

I am using Atom editor to view and edit the contents

Comment: `ionic start mproj blank` will create files in `src` directory.. `www` folder will get files once you build.. for eg: `ionic serve`

Comment: You got that right. But i still can't see any css, img, lib and js folders.

Comment: do you get any errors in the console? did you go to the folder and see? maybe you have configured atom to hide the folder?

Comment: No errors. I haven't touched any settings at all. My www folder has assets, build, index.html, manifest and service worker. Nothing else. (After checking from file explorer and not atom)

Comment: go to build folder. once built the files will be present there.. I guess you will have to check atom project settings

Comment: build has main, main.css.map, main, main.js.map, polyfills and sw-toolbox.  I am looking for another structure all together i suppose. with app.js. The tutorial i am referring to has a hierarchy totally different than what I have

Comment: depends on which tutorial.. ionic has changed considerably from 2 to 3.x.. Your code should work with minor changes if it is old tutorial..just compare with official docs

Comment: Got it. So the video I was watching was old. Back from 2015. Just popped up one from 3 months back - Ionic 2 and it seems the video has the same directory structure as mine. Thanks, Suraj. Cheers

Comment: Can you please leave an answer so that i can accept the answer and close this thread ?!

Comment: Alright.. added  most of the discussion to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ionic start mproj blank` will create files in `src` directory..

`www` folder will get files once you build for eg: `ionic serve`.

This will have `build` folder containing transpiled and minified css and js files.

ionic has changed considerably from 2 to 3.x.. Your code should work with minor changes if it is old tutorial..just compare with official docs

Comment: Where can I find the folder where ionic store my project and also path where it is installed?